# IOC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, entity, unity-container

I am trying to make use of Unity Framework with Entity Framework. Let me explain the scenario. Let's say I have a Database with 5 tables. I will have 5 interfaces each of them corresponding to one table in Database having each field of table as a member. Now I want my Entity Framework generated classes to implement corresponding table interface. All navigational properties should return objects as interface references. This should allow me to resolve these entities using Unity framework to allow any one to extend EF(data) entities without breaking required codes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no extensibility point for resolving entities with IoC container. EF will always handle instance creation of persisted entities. Morover EF mapping must work with classes not interfaces.

You can only handle `ObjectMaterialized` event on `ObjectContext` and provide some additional initialization of created entities.

You can try to add interfaces by implementing custom T4 template and including some convention (like name of the interface is always I + name of the entity) but still without IoC.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into this and yes regarding T4 templates I wrote my custom template for interfaces while modified the POCO template for classes. I need to look into ObjectMaterialized thing you mentioned. I was already afraid about EF only taking care of classes.