# ServiceStack Swapping ORMLite to Entity Framework

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to replace **ORMLite** to **EF5**, and please don't ask me why :P  ... So I searched around the net and have no luck finding much information on how to actually do this.

Do I need to rewrite `ORMLiteConnectionFactory` into `EFConnectionFactory` that registers in global.asax.cs? It seems like a lot to implement and very complex because it is linked to `IOrmLiteDialectProvider` `OrmLiteConfig` and all that, and it doesn't seem right because SS normally have a simple answer to all questions. For example, it is rather easy if I want to change Funq to another DI provider.

Is ORMLite the fixed choice of weapon or is this a flexible option that I can tune? Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all intents and purposes you're better off pretending OrmLite doesn't exist. OrmLite simply provides extension methods off ADO.NET's raw `IDbConnection` interfaces which works similar to (and why it is able to be used alongside with) Dapper and other Micro ORMS.

Entity Framework in contrast manages its own heavy abstraction that's by design not substitutable with other Micro ORMS, so you shouldn't attempt this route.

Simply ignore OrmLite exists and use Entity Framework as you normally would. Last I heard [EF doesn't play too nicely with IOCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279372/ioc-with-entity-framework) so you probably have to resort to the normal case of instantiating a new EF DataContext whenever you want to use it.