# Entity Framework and Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, factory-pattern

I'm attempting to implement the factory pattern with Entity Framework, but Entity Framework seems to call the default ctor and setters of each member whether they are private, or not.

Is there any way to get Entity Framework to call my `Object.Create()` instead?

***Edit:***

This is a simplified example of my class. I need entity framework to call the static Create() instead of the ctor.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Name { get; set; }
    public static Foo Create()
    {
        var newFoo = new Foo();
        newFoo.Init();
        return newFoo;
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        Name = "You know, on second thought, I want the name to be this instead.";
    }
    private Foo()
    {
        Name = "Hello Stack Overflow!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and what error you faced in code?

Comment: I've added a simple example of what I mean. I'm using `static Create()` to return an instance of my class after it has been changed by `Init()`. Is there a way to force Entity Framework to call Init()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could instead try searching for how to resolve or `Entities injection IoC` or similar - as that's requested more often, and basically need the same solution.

And second, usually (but not necessarily) **what you're trying to do suggests a bit awkward design** and could paint you into problems later on - actually, to me it suggests that you should seek different approach. Entities, POCO are not designed (again normally, it doesn't mean there isn't a case that warrants it) to be used in such way, and there're ways to work around such use. **Let the EF create and deal with them, and try to extract that initialization into some form of repository** or something. My suggestion at least...

Entity constructor is invoked internally (whether private or not) and as far as I know, even the latest EF 6 doesn't provide means for that. EF 6 has the `IDbDependencyResolver` but doesn't help in your case.

But what you could do is to '**inject into the object initialization**' process I think - also mentioned by Ladislav Mrmka in a similar context here [IOC with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279372/ioc-with-entity-framework)

You need to obtain the ref to `ObjectContext` as in:

`var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;`

...and then use the `objectContext.ObjectMaterialized` where the `ObjectMaterializedEventArgs` argument of the event has the `Entity` object.

You need to do additional casting there based on your type to get to the entity of yours.

I haven't worked with that for a while but might work what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The factory should only return an instance which adheres to an interface; thus returning an interface solely. Whether the instance was created by EF (and subsequently changing properties after creation but before being passed on) or a mocking framework will have no bearing to the consumer of the factory.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Entity Framework does not call the `Static Foo Create()` when it initially loads.

Comment: @CharlesW isn't EF pulling data from a database? If so why is there a need to call create? If a change in the properties is needed, the Factory pattern will call `Create` before sending it out; or change `Create` to `PostConstruction` which resides on a partial class which is called after construction from EF.

Comment: @CharlesW I believe that the factory should sit outside EF and use EF to create the initial objects, not that the factory resides in an EF instance/class.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do duck typing in generic method groups. And there is no such thing as static interface. So it is not really possible without creating some Factory class (instead of your static factory method) and passing instance of a factory to EF or some Resource-Locator or registry with all Factories it might need. However Entity Framework doesn't have such extensibility.

On the other hand, if you need such a control you might want to create your own mini framework on top of say [dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Answer (score -1):

//#1 Product Interface
//#2 Factory Method interface
//#3 Controller Class inherits from the Product and Method interface to produce your product
//#4 you can regenerate controller as many as business needs with different procedures inside Factory Method

//#5 create EF with a Subset of your Controller Class you need to record in DB
//#6